# Complicated sed command inside Perl script

Tags: perl, sed

I need to run a `sed` command inside a Perl script. But because the `sed` command is complicated, it does not run inside Perl. However, the `sed` command runs fine in shell.

Can someone please help?

File -

> cat /tmp/f1

```
"ABC": "abcd.com"
"Xris": [
"xyz.com"
"users": "user.com"
"id": "96444aa4b618.com"
```

---

Sed command on shell -

```
[]$ cat /tmp/f1 | sed  '/: \[.*$/ {s/\[//; N; s/\n//g; }'
"ABC": "abcd.com"
"XUrl": "xyz.com"
"users": "user.com"
"id": "96444aa4b618.com"
[]$
```

---

However, when this `sed` command is called in a Perl script, it complains. I have tried many different escape characters but it does not work. Usually it throws error -

```
[]$ cat script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
`sed -e '/: \[.*$/ {s/\[//; N; s/\n//g; }' /tmp/f1`;
[]$ ./script.pl
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated address regex
[]$
```

Please help with how this `sed` command can be run from inside a Perl script. Or is there any better way of running `sed` in a Perl script?

Comment: Perl can do anything `sed` can do — and then some.  There is no obvious reason to need to run `sed` from within Perl.  (There is/was a program `s2p` to convert a `sed` script to Perl — it was released up to Perl 5.20; it doesn't seem to be in my Perl 5.22 installation, so maybe it has been dropped now.  There was `a2p` to convert Awk to Perl too.)

Comment: How does `Xris:` get mapped to `XUrl:`?  Is that a typo in the question?

Comment: I see in the `perldoc perl5200delta` documentation: _**Utility removals**
    The following utilities will be removed from the core distribution in a
    future release, and will at that time need to be installed from CPAN. • find2perl • s2p
• a2p_ — so this is a documented change in status.  Running `perldoc perl5220delta` shows that the future release was indeed 5.22.0.

Comment: `echo "sed  '/: \[.*$/ {s/\[//; N; s/\n//g; }'"` gives an idea of the problem... Remember, backticks interpolate like double-quoted strings.

Comment: *I  need to run a `sed` command inside a Perl script* That is never true :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl can do the transformation that you're using `sed` to do, almost trivially.  I doubt if this is minimal Perl, but it works on the sample data, except it does not map `Xris` to `XUrl` (I assume that is a typo in the question).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    if (m/: \[.*$/)
    {
        chomp;
        my $next = <>;
        $_ =~ s/: \[.*/: /;
        $_ .= $next;
    }
    print;
}
```

When run on the data file from the question, the output is:

```
"ABC": "abcd.com"
"Xris": "xyz.com"
"users": "user.com"
"id": "96444aa4b618.com"
```

which is pretty much what was wanted.  You can probably revise the code so that the `chomp` is not necessary, but you need to remove the newline at the end of `$_` in the `if` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    if (m/: \[.*$/)
    {
        my $next = <>;
        $_ =~ s/: \[.*\n/: /;
        $_ .= $next;
    }
    print;
}
```

Same output from the same input.

Answer (score 2):

Backticks interpolate and process escapes just like double-quotes, so

```
`sed -e '/: \[.*$/ {s/\[//; N; s/\n//g; }' /tmp/f1`
```

is the same as

```
`sed -e '/: [.*
{s/[//; N; s/
//g; }' /tmp/f1`
```

You need

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('sed', '-e', '/: \\[.*$/ {s/\\[//; N; s/\\n//g; }', '/tmp/f1');
my $output = `$cmd`;
die("sed killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("sed exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
```

Of course, anything `sed` can do can easily be done in Perl itself. You'd be better off doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all..

Sorry there was typo in the question.

Got the sed command replaced by following and now its working fine-

```
while (<>)
{
    if (m/: \[.*$/)
    {
        my $next = <>;
        $_ =~ s/: \[.*\n/: /;
        $_ .= $next;
    }
    print;
}
```